# create customer in stripe with expresso cart when order is authorized

Tags: expresso-store, stripe

Is there a way with the current Stripe integration with Expresso cart to create a Customer and Card and on the Stripe side when an order is authorized?  If this does not exist in existing functionality in the Expresso cart does anyone have any code to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the Stripe payment gateway for Store does not do this. I don't imagine it would be that difficult though if you are comfortable with PHP.

First off, I'd suggest you make a copy of the Stripe gateway, rather than modify the original. Make sure it has a new name, which will involve renaming files, classes and directories, so that it comes up as a separate gateway.

From there, you'll need to reference the Stripe PHP documentation to alter the process, so a customer is created and charged, rather than just a charge being created.

If you're not comfortable with PHP, I'd suggest you get someone to do this for you, as it's a bit sticky to be mucking around with ecommerce functionality when you don't know what's going on. :)

Comment: I am fine with coding in PHP, I was just hoping to not have to code this myself.  I Was hoping that someone had already done and would be willing to share or sell code for it.  Oh well, time to start coding I guess.